# Is realm stable enough for production use?

Tags: realm

After reading the documentation on the website, I was very impressed with how easy it is to implement and use. However, I also noticed that it hasn't been officially released yet and it is still in beta.
I will soon start a new iOS project and I was wondering if realm is "stable" enough for production use. As many of you know, CoreData is a pain in the ___.

Thanks,

Comment: some people have nothing useful to do in their lives, so they down vote without even leaving a comment. That is a clear definition of a loser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the folks at realm, the framework has been used in production, however, developers should expect the API to evolve as this is still in a beta stage.