# Is it fine to use Realm Mobile Platform -beta version for a production app

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, mobile, realm

I am planning to use Realm Mobile Platform - free version (Developer Edition) for a production app. 
Since their product is in Beta, is it fine to still develop with Realm Mobile Platform?

I have Android, iOS and Website for my product. Mobile app helps in getting the data from the user and store it in the database. While I need to fetch this data from Realm object Server to show the content on the Website.

So is it fine to use Realm Mobile Platform for my use case, where I can have my own logic server side and will be able to use their server database to query from the Angular-based website?

Comment: `While I need to fetch this data from Realm object Server to show the content on the Website.` that doesn't sound like something that's in the free developer version, is it?

Comment: Right, that is my doubt, hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a personal project, go for it.
Some companies use realm.io in production, however expect some API changes after 1.0 as this is still in a beta stage.

Possible duplicate 
[Is realm stable enough for production use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384800/is-realm-stable-enough-for-production-use)